# Determining if graph is connected from degree sequence

Tags: graph-theory

The question is as in the title: How can I determine if a graph is connected from a degree sequence, for example $3,3,1,1,1,1$ ?

Is there any algorithm I can use?

Comment: Alex Ravsky is right, in general this is impossible. But there are some conditions. For $d=(d_1,\dotsc,d_n)$ to be the degree sequence of a _disconnected_ graph, it must be possible to partition $d$ into two parts that each have even sum and other restrictions of degree sequences, e.g., each part has length strictly greater than its largest entry. For $d=(3,3,1,1,1,1,1)$, a part that includes a $3$ has length at least $4$. The only candidate is $(3,3,1,1)$ with $(1,1)$. The $(3,3,1,1)$ can't occur for a simple graph (only if parallel edges are allowed).

Answer (score 2):

In general, this is impossible even for simple regular graphs. For instance, a degree sequence $2,2,2,2,2,2$ corresponds both to a cycle $C_6$, which is connected and to a union of two disjoint cycles $C_3$, which is disconnected.